# The attribute 'cacheable' is not allowed

Tags: magento2, checkout, error, bug

```
Element 'referenceBlock', attribute 'cacheable': The attribute 'cacheable' is not allowed.
```

when I click checkout button that error occurs

My magento version is 2.3.5 so that must not be the problem
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjJMW.png
how may I fix?

Comment: Any third party extension are called checkout?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya I have Installed MageTop extension but it has nothing like checkout Think so

Comment: Try to disable that one and then check.

Comment: its disabled. still nothing.

Comment: Can you try with all third party extension one by one, or you can search that work in all third party extension xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was database related.